# Using SELECT with a display condition

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
SELECT DISTINCT Invoice.InvNo, Invoice.OrderNo, Part.PartNo,
  orders.orddate AS Order_Date, Invoice.InvDate AS Bill_Date,
  MiscChg.Descr, MiscChg.RegFee, Invoice.InvAmt, 
  Orders.ClaimNo, Firm.FirmName AS Ordering_Firm, 
**oppatty.attyid(WHERE oppatty.attyfor = 13)**, Location.Name1 AS Location
```

The bolded section is the part I'm having trouble with. I know what I have isn't right, but it demonstrates what I would like to accomplish. In the oppatty table, there could be several items listed. I want it to only display "AttyID for the entry that has an ATTYFOR = 13".

Hope this make sense, thanks

Jack

Comment: Looks like there may be a one to many relationship between oppatty and some other table in your query.  If that's the case you could put the `AND oppatty.attyfor` on the JOIN criteria between oppatty and the other table(s).  If you want all records even those not oppatty.attyfor 13, then make it a `OUTER LEFT join`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `CASE WHEN` to the select statement.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Invoice.InvNo, 
    Invoice.OrderNo, 
    Part.PartNo, 
    orders.orddate AS Order_Date, 
    Invoice.InvDate AS Bill_Date, 
    MiscChg.Descr, 
    MiscChg.RegFee, 
    Invoice.InvAmt, 
    Orders.ClaimNo, 
    Firm.FirmName AS Ordering_Firm, 
    CASE WHEN oppatty.AttyFor = 13
         THEN oppatty.AttyId
         ELSE '' END AS attyfor, 
    Location.Name1 AS Location
FROM
    .........
```

This will display the `AttyId` field when the row's `AttyFor` field is equal to 13 and show an empty string when it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Your query has no from or where clause and your question is a bit jumbled, but even so, I think I understand what you want to do. Assuming it's acceptable to fill the "AttyID" values with null where "AttyFor" isn't equal to 13, then you could just use a case statement. Try something like this

```
select
    stuff.things,
    case 
        where oppatty.attyfor <> 13 then null
        else oppatty.attyid
    end as attyid,
    stuff.others
from
    oppatty
    join stuff on oppatty.ID = stuff.ID
```

If that's not your desired result, and you'd rather entirely exclude rows where "AttyFor" isnt equal to 13, then just use a where clause.

```
select
    stuff.things,
    oppatty.attyid,
    stuff.others
from
    oppatty
    join stuff on oppatty.ID = stuff.ID
where
    oppatty.attyfor = 13
```